# point function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, gis

i have a question about the function Point ( Lat, Long, SRID ) in this syntax what is SRID and where we get it ?

Comment: Why don't you just google it?

Comment: i did but couldn't get clear idea

Answer (score 0):

With the documentation you can find in [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-reference-identifiers-srids)

> The SRID corresponds to a spatial reference system based on the
>   specific ellipsoid used for either flat-earth mapping or round-earth
>   mapping

As you may know every geopgraphic system are only projection from the real to data we can use. If you don't define in wich SRID you are same coordinate can pointed to places who are far away.